# Why can't my code go straight into the if body when the user input "m"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My code will not compare the if statement correctly. When the user input "m", it will not output whatever it is in the if body

```
int main()
{
    char name[50];
    char gender[50];
    int num_gender=0; //calculate the characters in gender
    cout<<"Please input your name ";
    cin>>name;
cout<<"Gender ";
    cout<<" (m=male f=female) ";
    cin>>gender;
    num_gender=strlen(gender);
    if(num_gender!=1)
  {
    cout<<"Please enter m or f only";
  }
  if(gender=="m" || gender=="f")
    {
        if(gender=="m")
        {
          cout<<"hello Mr."<<name<<endl;    
        }
        if( gender=="f" )
        cout<<"hello Ms."<<name<<endl;
    }
```

}

I expect the output will be hello Mr. or hello Ms. followed by the name entered instead of nothing

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of an array of char

Comment: As has been said, use `std::string` not arrays of `char` to do this. It's easier (and more reliable). Here's how `#include <string> std::string name; std::string gender; num_gender = gender.size();` and most importantly `gender == "m"` now works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare `string` objects using `operator==`. You cannot compare `char*` or `char[]` this way, as it numerically compares the pointers, not the strings themselves. Since the compiler will reserve three different memory locations for `"m"`, `"f"` and `gender`, `gender=="m"` and `gender=="f"` can never be true.

To compare `char*` or `char[]` as strings, use C function `strcmp`.